# Identifying the child window of a web application without the child window name or Id

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am automating a web application in which, onclick of a hyperlink opens a window that doesnt have a url tab. The child window contains some controls, whose operations need to be automated. I dont have the child window Id or name. please help , I am blocked by this Issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `UITestControl` object for the window or a relevant child control then the `UITestControl.GetChildren` method will return all the child controls. You can easily iterate through the children, or possibly do a recursive trawl through them searching to find the control you need. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.getchildren.aspx